# What is a good click through rate (CTR)

Tags: google-ads

I'm new to adwords and I'm trying to figure out what a good click through rate on my ads would be.   Does anyone have any guidelines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers quoted below seem about right for campaigns which I've run (I'd add that the most abysmal CTR I've seen was 10k:1 for a banner ad on a site which ran multiple banner ads - it ran for three months, had millions of views, and resulted in three conversions, all of which canceled within their first month).

> - Low conversion rate 1:500.
> - Ordinary 1:100
> - Good 1:5
> - Unbelievable 1:1
>
> ---
>
> - Low CTR: 0.5%
> - Ordinary: 2.5%
> - Good: 10%
> - Outstanding: 60%

Source: [What is the typical CTR and conversion ranges?](http://www.google.fi/support/forum/p/AdWords/thread?tid=4c7dc30160b74e40&hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

A bit off topic, but this is my general proceeding to improve CTRs:

1. Being ruthless with low CTRs below the average for a period (a month usually).
2. Increase the max bid on the better ones if needed.
3. Search for keywords similar/related to the ones with better CTRs.
4. Wait until the keywords reach a decent number of impressions and repeat the process.

I often have to "fight" with the customer to get rid of general keywords with poor CTRs but a high number of impressions, but eventually is usually worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, and I hope I am not opening myself to ridicule via honesty but...I have a client, who was running (although mismanaged) AdWords nearly 2 years before I started with them (a year ago).

They are a smaller, local, non-glamorous business (Junk Removal in a medium city), if their search campaigns do better than 5% CTR, I am happy. Display .1% or better makes me happy...but that is also nearly double their historical average.

Like AJweb said, anything underperforming I have to fight with them to remove...they don't really grasp relevancy in spite of numerous discussions. And if (for search) I see less than 1% CTR I take a hard look at it.